# openzeppelin mint sequence

Tags: openzeppelin, inheritance, solidity-0.5.x

```
// openzeppelin v5
contract ERC721Full is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721Metadata {
    constructor (string memory name, string memory symbol) public ERC721Metadata(name, symbol) {
        // solhint-disable-previous-line no-empty-blocks
    }
}


contract Test is ERC721Full {   
   // ctor...

  function createToken(...) public {
    _mint(msg.sender, id);
  }
}
```

Basically, I have a contract that inherits openzeppelin's `ERC721Full` contract.

My question is, when `_mint` is called in `createToken`, why does it call `_mint` in `ERC721Enumerable` instead of `_mint` in `ERC721`?

Is it because `ERC721Enumerable` is inherited in `ERC721Full` next to `ERC721` in the sequence?

ex: ERC721 -> ERC721Enumerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer myself. It's because solidity uses [c3 linearlization](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#multiple-inheritance-and-linearization).

> Another simplifying way to explain this is that when a function is called that is defined multiple times in different contracts, the given bases are searched from right to left (left to right in Python)

So I was kinda right in that it searches from right to left.

Comment: If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin